# Type promotion/conversion

Tags: c, 64-bit

The result of the sizeof operator appears to be of type size_t, which is defined as unsigned long long on Windows 64-bit.

Considering the following piece of (pseudo) code:

```
int func(unsigned long arg)
{
    /* ... */
}

/* ... */

unsigned long herp = 3,
              derp = 5,
              durr = 7;

wchar_t wut;

func(/* ... */);
```

What actually happens here in terms of type promotion/conversion when func is called as follows?

```
func((herp + derp) * durr * sizeof wut); // 1st example
```

Are the values of herp, derp, and durr first promoted to unsigned long longs and then after the result is evaluated, the result is converted back to unsigned long?

And instead, when calling func as follows, is the only conversion that takes place the type cast to unsigned long?

```
func((herp + derp) * durr * (unsigned long)sizeof wut); // 2nd example
```

Taking type conversion/promotion into consideration, what is the most appropriate/correct way to call func?

Comment: `(herp + derp)` knows nothing about `size_t` and so is not promoted. But values for an arithmetical calculation are promoted to the native integer type before calculation, if shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When confronted with an arithmetic operator whose arguments are different sizes, the compiler applies the ["Usual Arithmetic Conversions"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8), which basically make both operands the same type.

This is performed throughout an expression, one operator at a time. The expression is analysed into individual operations according to the syntax of C; the compiler is not allowed to modify the parse unless it can prove that the result makes no difference (in which case the modification was more or less irrelevant).

So, consider your expression:

```
func((herp + derp) * durr * sizeof wut);
```

That's syntactically equivalent to the following series of operations, in which types and conversions have been omitted (for now):

```
temp1 = herp + derp;
temp2 = temp1 * durr;
temp3 = sizeof wut
temp4 = temp2 * temp3;
temp5 = (unsigned long) temp4;
func(temp5)
```

The first four temporaries are automatically typed to the result type of each operator (which is the type produced by the Usual Arithmetic Conversions for that operator).

1. `temp1 = herp + derp;`

   `herp` and `derp` are both `unsigned long`; no conversion is necessary; the result type is `unsigned long`.
2. `temp2 = temp1 * durr;`

   `temp1` and `durr` are both `unsigned long`; no conversion is necessary; the result type is `unsigned long`.
3. `temp3 = sizeof wut;`

   `sizeof` always returns `size_t`, so that is the type of the result.
4. `temp4 = temp2 * temp3`

   `temp2` is `unsigned long` and `temp3` is `size_t`, which on the example platform is `unsigned long long`. This requires a conversion of `temp2` to `unsigned long long`, after which the result type is `unsigned long long`.

So we can insert types and conversions into the sample code above:

```
unsigned long temp1 = herp + derp;
unsigned long temp2 = temp1 * durr;
unsigned long long temp3 = sizeof wut
unsigned long long temp4 = (unsigned long long)temp2 * temp3;
temp5 = (unsigned long)temp4;
func(temp5)
```

The key take-away here is that the fact that a result will be converted to some other type has *no effect* on its computation. The compiler cannot decide to not apply the usual arithmetic conversion, or to apply an unusual arithmetic conversion (perhaps narrowing an argument instead of widening the other one) unless it can prove that the end result will be, in all cases, the same as the one mandated by the standard. (Here, "in all cases" actually means "in all cases which do not exhibit undefined behaviour", but since unsigned arithmetic is well-defined with the exception of divide/modulo by 0, this detail is not relevant in this example.)

If the expression involves division operators, then overflow will actually matter. Consider the case of

```
(a + b) * c * (sizeof x) / (sizeof y)
```

where `a`, `b` and `c` are all the same type, which is narrower than `size_t`.

As with the logic above, `(a + b) * c` is evaluated in the common type of `a`, `b` and `c`. Then that result is promoted to a `size_t` so that it can be multiplied by the size of `x`. But it is certainly possible that `(a + b) * c` will have overflowed before the conversion, making the end result invalid. It would have been safer to insist that the entire computation be performed with `size_t` operands. This could be accomplished by adding a single explicit conversion:

```
((size_t)a + b) * c * (sizeof x) / (sizeof y)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Your explanation is highly appreciated and has helped me to better understand arithmetic conversions.